# I want to put image who are not on the dom in a nodeList

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have googled a lot in stackOverflow and other sources but all I can find are nodeLists pulled from the Dom. I created my own elements in the js file and i want to put the in an array to be able to manipulate the order.

Can you help me where I'm wrong.

Obviously this didn't work. The images are correctly created but the nodeList is not rightly declared.

```
const img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "../img/afghanistan.png";
img1.alt = "afghanistan";
img1.width = widthCalculation();
img1.height = heightCalculation();

const img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "../img/angola.png";
img2.alt = "angola";
img2.width = widthCalculation();
img2.height = heightCalculation();

const img3 = new Image();
img3.src = "../img/bahamas.png";
img3.alt = "bahamas";
img3.width = widthCalculation();
img3.height = heightCalculation();

const img4 = new Image();
img4.src = "../img/belgium.png";
img4.alt = "belgium";
img4.width = widthCalculation();
img4.height = heightCalculation();

const img5 = new Image();
img5.src = "../img/bolivia.png";
img5.alt = "bolivia";
img5.width = widthCalculation();
img5.height = heightCalculation();

const img6 = new Image();
img6.src = "../img/kiribati.png";
img6.alt = "kiribati";
img6.width = widthCalculation();
img6.height = heightCalculation();

const img7 = new Image();
img7.src = "../img/mongolia.png";
img7.alt = "mongolia"
img7.width = widthCalculation();
img7.height = heightCalculation();

const img8 = new Image();
img8.src = "../img/panama.png";
img8.alt = "panama";
img8.width = widthCalculation();
img8.height = heightCalculation();

let imgCollection = { const img1, const img2 ,img3 ,img4 ,img5 ,img6 ,img7, img8 };
```

Comment: A nodeList is purely a DOM object that cannot be created without the help of a DOM selector of some type. So this cannot be done.

Comment: Its really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the NodeList? If you explain your intent we can - probably - suggest an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following:

```
const img1 = new Image();
```

Use this instead:

```
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
```

The latter will create an element that you can configure and then append to your collection.

```js
var images = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = `img${i}.png`;
  images.push(img);
}

console.log(images);
```

Comment: Thanks, i made a workaround but this might help further on.